# Join - Pig scripts

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig, hadoop-partitioning

Iam new to Pig scripts. I need help in joining 'B' and 'E'. Below is my script.

```
    A = LOAD ....
    PAPS_1 = FILTER A BY (dataMap#'corr_id_' is NOT null);
    B = FOREACH PAPS_1 GENERATE dataMap#'corr_id_' as id, dataMap#'response' as resp, status;
    C = LOAD ..
    D = FILTER C BY (dataMap#'corr_id_' is NOT null);
    E = FOREACH D GENERATE dataMap#'corr_id_' as id, status;
```

I tried joining like this. But it doesn't work. I am getting null values. Please correct me.

```
F = JOIN B BY id, E BY id;
```

**Values in B:**

23456ac, 200, 0

3453da3, 200, 0

**Values in C:**

23456ac, 0

3453da3, 0

**Values in E:**

23456ac, 0

3453da3, 0

**My output is:**

NULL, 200, 0, NULL, 0

NULL, 200, 0, NULL, 0

**Expected is**:

23456ac, 200, 0, 23456ac, 0

3453da3, 200, 0, 3453da3, 0

Thanks In Advance

Comment: add values contained by B and E in question

Comment: check the data type of id. Is both id have the same data type, if not cast with the same datatype.

Comment: What does E contain?